# Test device for DirectShow development

Tags: windows, testing, directshow

I'm writing a program that is supposed to work with a variety of webcams via DirectShow.

To test with many different devices, I'm looking for (software) devices that provide test images in different resolutions and color formats.

I already found MayCam, but would like to have many more test devices, espcially some that support color formats other than BGR24 (for example YUV2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no standard test device, you might possibly find a third party virtual video source capable of delivering video in multiple formats, however the reliably working but time consuming path is to take `PushSource` sample from Windows SDK and update it appropriately to convert it into a test source device.